# SignalR Get Clients outside of Hub not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, signalr

I am trying to call signalR from a controller, but it doesnt work.

**Controller**:

```
public ActionResult Index(){
   var hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ClientControl>();
   hub.Clients.All.sendMessage("ahahhaaa");
   //... return and staff
}
```

**Hub**

```
[Authorize]
[HubName("userTracking")]
public class ClientControl : Hub
{

    public void RegisterConnection(String controller, String action)
    {

    }
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {

    }
    public override Task OnDisconnected()
    {

        return base.OnDisconnected();
    }

}
```

**Frontend**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var trackhub = $.connection.userTracking;
    trackhub.client.sendMessage = function (msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
    $.connection.hub.logging = true;
    $.connection.hub.start();
});
```

In the controller it doesnt throw an error. When I debug and pause it, hub object exists, but when I perform it, it sends no message to the frontend. If I call the same method from the hub - works as a charm.
Any idea, what can be the root cause of the problem? If needed - write in the comments I will provide more info.

Comment: what you exactly want to do ?

Comment: Send a message progress from controller

Comment: Did you manage to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Server

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{

        public int TryAddNewUser(string userName)
        {
            //some logic...
            Clients.All.AddUserToUserList(id, userName);
            return id;
        }

        public void AddNewMessageToPage(int id, string message)
        {
            //some logic...
            Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(u.Login, message);
        }

}
```

Client

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //first need register client methods
    var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
    chat.client.addUserToUserList = function (id, login) {
        //client logic for add new user
    }

    chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (login, message) {
        //client logic for add new message from user
    }

    //second need start chat
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        chat.server.tryAddNewUser(login).done(function (id) {
            alert("Added " + id)
        });
    });

});
```

Controller

```
public class ChatController : Controller
{
   private IMyDataService _service;
   public ChatController(IMyDataService s)
   {
      _service = s;
   }

   public ActionResult Index()
   {
      return View(new MyDataViewModel(_service));
   }

}
```

Note, dynamic js file must be added with the same path

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

And i add following code to Startup.cs

```
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;

    [assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(ChatRoom.Startup))]
    namespace ChatRoom
    {
        public class Startup
        {
            public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
            {
                // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
                app.MapSignalR();
            }
        }
    }
```

About this see [link](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/releases/upgrading-signalr-1x-projects-to-20)

Comment: eee and a controller?

Answer (score 0):

Please change the hub name in controller to work

Use

```
var hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<UserTracking>();
       hub.Clients.All.sendMessage("ahahhaaa");
```

Instead of

```
var hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ClientControl>();
       hub.Clients.All.sendMessage("ahahhaaa");
```

Please note the change in Hub Class Name in **GetHubContext<>**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: not gonna work, UserTracking is a name for JS not for  a backend

Comment: "UserTracking is a name for JS not for a backend" what you mean by this?

Comment: I call it from JS as var trackhub = $.connection.userTracking; In C# code (server/controller, whatever you want to call it), there is not such a thing, it is just an attribute